# jQuery quandary with $(this).next or $(this).parent

Tags: jquery, parent

Using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.toggle").removeClass('hide'); 
    $('p.extra_text').hide();
    $('a.toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('div.bios').next('p.extra_text').slideToggle("slow", function(){ 
            $('a.toggle').text(function (index, text) {
                return (text == 'Read More . . .' ? 'Read Less . . .' : 'Read More . . .'); 
            });
        });    
        return false;
    });
});
```

with:

```
<div class="bios">      
  <p><strong>A Nobody</strong></p>
  <p>A Nobody live in Anywhere, USA.<a class="toggle hide">Read More . . .</a></p>
  <p class="extra_text">Wonder who A Nobody really is?  Well, we do too!</p>    

  <p><strong>A Nobody</strong></p>
  <p>A Nobody live in Anywhere, USA.<a class="toggle hide">Read More . . .</a></p>
  <p class="extra_text">Wonder who A Nobody really is?  Well, we do too!</p>    
 </div><!--/bios-->
```

When any `a class="toggle"` is clicked, all `p class="extra_text"` slideToggle.  How to tie each successive `a class="toggle"` to its own `p class="extra_text"`?

I've seen other answers using `$(this).next` or `$(this).parent`, but they fail because there's that other p before the `p class="extra_text"`.  How may I best select the correct, successive `a class="toggle"` / `p class="extra_text"` combo without triggering all  of 'em with my Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You want `$(this).parent().next()`.

Comment: Just one fast OT: Why have you resigned?

Comment: I don't really have the patience to deal with moderation issues; I prefer to spend my time answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks pointed out `$(this).parent().next()` is what your looking for but your text function will change every class, instead do this:

```
$('a.toggle').click(function() {
    var link = this;

    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(link).text(function(index, text) {
            return (text == 'Read More . . .' ? 'Read Less . . .' : 'Read More . . .');
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/KuQPP/

**EDIT**

I usually don't go this far to explain how something works but in this case pictures speak louder then words and was in a generous mood I created this little diagram of why your code doesn't work and this way does.

**Explanation Diagram**

[image]

Comment: I may be missing a critical point, but what happened to p.extra_test in this script?  Does .parent = p.extra_test?  I've added the above to my work, but no joy.  Ideas welcome.

Comment: No the next() method is that element, parent() is the p element with the shown text with the element with the a link.  So the parent of a element is the p element it's in, the next element after p is the extra text p.

Comment: Jeff:Well, I feel like Arlo Guthrie at the crime scene from "Alices's Restaurant" - 8x10's with arrows and all . . . Couldn't ask for more.  Of course, once explained clearly, it's very simple.  Good treat for Thanksgiving, so thanks for your generosity and the fiddle example, too.

Comment: One more basic question: When I leave js in page, all is well, but when I create a .js file containing code and 'source' it from another file, the .hide() function fails.  Virus at the keyboard (me) or a quirk?

Comment: If it works on the page but not in the a js file then either **1.** Your including the <script> tags in your js file or **2.** Your including your js file before the jquery library, it needs to go after.  Also **3.** I don't have the hide portion in my code in case you were copying it verbatim; If you want elements hidden on load you shouldn't be doing it with Javascript like that.  You should just create a css style for it `hide {display: none;}`

Comment: Gotcha.  One more: how can I add a link within the slideToggled p.extra_text without having it triggered by your var = link?  A way to distinguish it from the other More, Less links . . . ?  ID, maybe?

Comment: You can add a link to your p.extra_text element just like a normal link.  The "read more" `a` element event is trigger based on the class `toggle` as shown in this code `$('a.toggle').click(function() {
` if an `a` element has the class of `toggle` then it gets executed.  Simply add your links to your p.extra_text element without the class toggle.

Comment: J: Yep, added a link with another class designation and it worked as you've explained.  Thanx for all your explanations.